# After Spring framework upgrade from 3.2.9 to 5.3.22 and URL ending with .html stop working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have one application that is using Spring framework version 3.2.9.RELEASE and upgraded to 5.3.22 and With this, I have not made any configuration changes so far.

My DispatcherServlet.xml and all the web.xml configurations are as is.

But before this upgrade, I have a controller with @RequestMapping("/ssoLogin") and if I use the URL **"ssoLogin.html"**, it was able to find the controller, but after this upgrade it is not able to do so.

Below is my web.xml dispatcher server config

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Below is the view resolver configuration

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
                      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <!--To maintain HTTPS state -->
    <property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Till now no config change and the URL ending with .html extension was working fine and after upgrade it is not working and getting 404 not found error in browser.

Comment: If you would take the time to read the upgrade guide (for all of the versions). You would have encountered [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#use-of-path-extensions-deprecated-in-spring-mvc). Which explains it (and has links to other parts on how to enabe it again).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @M. Deinum
Your comment helped me.

To solve this problem, I went though the below links

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24179

https://github.com/lamsfoundation/lams/commit/7ff6d4b34cd71ac45741cb7c8d0c3ef6909eadf4

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23915#issuecomment-563987147

And based on this I made below change in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="true" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And this has solved my problem.